# Polymer CLI Build | Cache Busting Techniques

Tags: caching, polymer, browser-cache, polymer-cli

**A little background:** 
My app is built on Polymer 2.x and is being hosted on a server that does not support HTTP/2 and does not have a certificate for HTTPS.  We must support IE11, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

**Problem:**
I'm running into an issue with browser caching.  I was hoping to use the service worker that the Polymer CLI generates to handle the cache busting.  However, since our client's server doesn't have HTTPS enabled, we are unable to utilize it.  Regardless, we have to support IE 11 on a single build, so service workers aren't an option.

I cannot figure out a way to bust the cache on new deployments.  On the Polymer CLI github page, there is an open issue regarding this topic, but there hasn't been any traction since 2016.  From watching the YouTube videos on Polymer, it looks like there is (or used to be) a way to intercept the build using Gulp, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using polymer CLI to create a build of your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of the Polymer CLI (as of 7/18/17).  In the polymer.json file, it is set to build a bundled version of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `polymer-build` library if you want to build a Polymer project using `gulp`. You can read about it here:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-build

Briefly mentioned in the docs here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production#use-polymer-build

Then you can cache bust using something like `gulp-rev`, but you have to make sure that you're not rewriting the custom element names, just the filenames and import paths. (I tried this once with `gulp-rev-all`, and by default it was replacing `<app-header>` with `<app-header-a9fe00>` or something like that.)

Answer (score 0):

While creating the build run `polymer build sw-precache-config.js`

Answer (score 0):

I've created [gulp-polymer-build](https://github.com/bendavis78/gulp-polymer-build) to help with this very issue. It borrows from `polymer-cli build` code, and supports your build configs in `polymer.json`. It allows you to modify your source stream before building, and then modify the forked streams for all builds you've configured in `polymer.json`. This makes it easy to use `gulp-rev` and `gulp-rev-replace` to do asset versioning.